# Is it possible to create an Umbraco site from the Azure Marketplace using powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, umbraco, azure-marketplace

I keep getting requests to set up Umbraco sites for developers.

I have done a bit of searching and, I am wondering if it is possible to use powershell to create an Umbraco site ***from the Azure Marketplace using powershell***.

I create VMs, for example, using the following commands:

- Get-AzureVMImage
- New-AzureQuickVM

But I cand find any for websites (web apps) from the market place.

**There is what I would use to do in in the portal:**
[image]

**Note**: it must be done using the market place.

Update to question:
I have got further with this thanks to @theadriangreen.

**Now I have the following after I run the command:**

siteName: the website name

hostingPlanName: Basic

serverFarmResourceGroup: ***I have no idea***

siteLocation: Australia Southeast

serverName: ***is this the database server name?***

serverLocation: Australia Southeast

administratorLogin: ***is this the database admin login name?***

databaseName: ***is this the database admin login password?***

webDeploy_DatabaseUsername: ***no idea***

webDeploy_DatabasePassword: ***no idea***

@theadriangreen I hope you can clarify some of these for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. From the command `Get-AzureResourceGroupGalleryTemplate` we are able to locate the template identity as `umbracoorg.UmbracoCMS.0.4.6-preview`, hence the powershell command is:

```
Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureResourceManager
Add-AzureAccount
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId '<subscription-id>'
New-AzureResourceGroup -Name testrg -Location westus -DeploymentName testrg -GalleryTemplateIdentity umbracoorg.UmbracoCMS.0.4.6-preview
```

Looking at the template (https://gallerystoreprodch.blob.core.windows.net/prod-microsoft-windowsazure-gallery/umbracoorg.UmbracoCMS.0.4.6-preview/DeploymentTemplates/Website_NewHostingPlan_SQL_NewDB-Default.json) which we get from `Get-AzureResourceGroupGalleryTemplate -Identity umbracoorg.UmbracoCMS.0.4.6-preview` we can infer the following about the parameters:

- siteName: the website name
- hostingPlanName: Name of the app server plan to use.
- serverFarmResourceGroup: Must be the same as the resource group name
- siteLocation: location
- serverName: MSSQL Server name
- serverLocation: location, should be the same as above
- administratorLogin: MSSQL admin login
- databaseName: MSSQL admin login password
- webDeploy_DatabaseUsername: MSSQL admin login provided to the app, should be the same as above
- webDeploy_DatabasePassword: MSSQL admin login password provided to the app, should be the same as above

Comment: thanks for this. I will edit my question as you have helped me a lot but I have a couple more things to clarify. Wait 3 minutes an ill have the question edited.

Comment: thanks Awesome. One last thing. how do I use an existing SQL database server. I have reached my quote of 6 database server so I want to use an existing server. But it seems to only want to create a new one.

Comment: There is a way to create an app using an existing DB but it's outside the scope of a comment. If you ask another question I can answer it.